# backfill data evenly between dates

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe below, where data is released on a weekly basis but I need daily reading. I will assume the number is accumulated evenly on a daily basis before released

So I need to backfill the NAN from

```
effective_date
    2022-04-18         NaN
    2022-04-19         NaN
    2022-04-20         NaN
    2022-04-21         NaN
    2022-04-22   5
    2022-04-25         NaN
    2022-04-26         NaN
    2022-04-27         NaN
    2022-04-28         NaN
    2022-04-29    1
    2022-05-02         NaN
    2022-05-03         NaN
    2022-05-04         NaN
    2022-05-05         NaN
    2022-05-06         NaN
```

to desired df

```
effective_date
    2022-04-18         1
    2022-04-19         1
    2022-04-20         1
    2022-04-21         1
    2022-04-22   1
    2022-04-25         0.25
    2022-04-26         0.25
    2022-04-27         0.25
    2022-04-28         0.25
    2022-04-29    0.25
    2022-05-02         NaN
    2022-05-03         NaN
    2022-05-04         NaN
    2022-05-05         NaN
    2022-05-06         NaN
```

df.fillna(method='bfill') does not work because it fills the same value, where as I want the value adjusted as described above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add tags for the language you are using. If it is Python/Pandas, have you tried using the `.bfill()` method and if you have, please show your code and any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

fixed with this, mixture of resample and bfill.

```
(df.resample('d')
            .bfill()
            .div(5)
            .reset_index()
            .set_index('effective_date')
            )
```